# How to use request in Rails outside a def function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In this source block, I want to set `basePath` for different environment domains. For example, these:

- ENV1: http://abc.def.com/ghi/
- ENV2: http://ghi.abc.def.com/

```
class ApidocsController < ApplicationController
    include Swagger::Blocks

    BASE_PATH = request.original_url.include?("def.com/ghi") ? '/ghi/' : '/'

    swagger_root do
    ┆ key :swagger, '2.0'
    ┆ info do
    ┆ ┆ key :version, '1.0.0'
    ┆ ┆ key :title, 'Demo API'
    ┆ ┆ key :description, 'Demo API'
    ┆ ┆ contact do
    ┆ ┆ ┆ key :name, 'Demo'
    ┆ ┆ end
    ┆ end
    ┆ key :host, ENV['HOST']
    ┆ key :basePath, BASE_PATH
    ┆ key :consumes, ['application/json']
    ┆ key :produces, ['application/json']
    end

    # A list of all classes that have swagger_* declarations.
    SWAGGERED_CLASSES = [
    ┆ PostController,
    ┆ self,
    ].freeze

    def index
    ┆ render json: Swagger::Blocks.build_root_json(SWAGGERED_CLASSES)
    end
  end
```

But caused error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (undefined local variable or method `request' for ApidocsController:Class\nDid you mean?  require)
```

It seems that `request` only work in a `def` function. But in this case, how to check the original_url to set different basePath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, should use merge to inject:

https://github.com/fotinakis/swagger-blocks/blob/master/README.md#overriding-attributes

```
def index
  base_path = request.original_url.include?("def.com/ghi") ? '/ghi/' : '/'
  render json: Swagger::Blocks.build_root_json(SWAGGERED_CLASSES).merge({basePath: base_path})
end
```